# Underline with stars from first non-space character

Tags: bash

I am using this bash function to print a phrase with stars below it.

```
outline ()
{
 titl="$1"
 n="${#titl}"
 st=$( printf '%*s' $n " " | tr ' ' '*' )
 printf '%s\n' "$titl" "$st"
}
```

The result of `outline "Stack Overflow"` will be

```
1234567890123456
Stack Overflow
**************
```

But with three spaces before the first letter `S`, the command `outline "   Stack Overflow"` gives

```
12345678901234567890 
   Stack Overflow
*****************
```

I want to start the stars from the beginning of the first non-space character, so that the result of `outline "   Stack Overflow"` will be

```
12345678901234567890 
   Stack Overflow
   **************
```

Have including column numbers on top to understand where things are to be placed.

Comment: Works fine on this side, I can't reproduce your result.

Comment: With bash `st="${titl//?/*}"; printf '%s\n' "$titl" "$st"` Without the `tr`

Comment: There are spaces in the beginning of `titl` which do not show very well.

Comment: Does not do the job though because `outline "   Stock"` prints three stars before the first letter `S`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In pure bash:

```
outline () {
    local leading_blanks=${1%%[![:blank:]]*}
    local trimmed=${1#"$leading_blanks"}
    printf '%s\n%s%s\n' "$1" "$leading_blanks" "${trimmed//?/*}"
}

outline "   Stack Overflow"
```

**Explanation:**

- `${1%%[![:blank:]]*}` deletes from the first non-blank character through end of string, from `$1`. Remaining characters are just leading blanks, if any.
- `${1#"$leading_blanks"}` removes the leading blank characters (if any) from `$1`.
- `"${trimmed//?/*}"` replaces each character in the variable `trimmed` with a `*`.

For detailed information about all types of parameter expansion in bash, read [Shell Parameter Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

Alternatively, a single `sed` command will do the job, though, I would definitely prefer the pure bash version:

```
outline () {
sed 'h
     s/^[[:blank:]]*//
     s/./*/g
     H
     g
     s/^\([[:blank:]]*\)\(.*\n\)\(.*\)/\1\2\1\3/' <<< "$1"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this works for all non-space characters: would your teacher accept it?

```
outline ()
{
 titl="$1"
 printf '%s\n%s\n' "${titl}" "${titl//[! ]/*}"
}

outline "  Stack Overflow"
  Stack Overflow
  ***** ********
```

Comment: Spaces should also be starred unless they occur at the beginning.

Comment: It is not important what some teacher accepts.

Answer (score 1):

With `bash`:

```
outline ()
{ 
  local titl spaces
  titl="$1"
  
  # extract leading spaces
  [[ $titl =~ ^(\ )* ]]; spaces="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
  
  # remove leading spaces from titl
  titl="${titl/#$spaces/}"
  
  echo "$spaces$titl"
  echo "$spaces${titl//?/*}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With only bash the following does what you show, thanks to the extended pattern matching (`extglob`) option:

```sh
outline () {
  restore="$(shopt -p extglob)"
  shopt -s extglob
  spc="${1/[^[:space:]]*}"
  str="${1##+([[:space:]])}"
  printf '%s\n%s\n' "$1" "$spc${str//?/*}"
  eval "$restore"
}
```

Explanation: first record the current `extglob` status such that it can be restored before leaving the function. Then store the leading spaces in variable `spc` and the rest in variable `str`. Finally, print the original string, followed by a line formed by `$spc` and `$str` where each character has been replaced by a star.

A one-liner with sed (tested with GNU sed):

```sh
outline () {
  sed -E 'p;s/^([[:space:]]*)./\1*/;:a;s/\*[^*]/**/;ta' <<< "$1"
}
```

Explanation: first print the string. Next, substitute the first non-space character by a star. Then substitute a star followed by a non-star character by two stars and repeat as long as there is a match. Finally sed automatically prints the result.

Comment: This suffers from the problem that the preceding spaces before the first letter are removed.

Comment: @Phil: If that's not what you want, then you must have messed up the formatting in your question. Please fix it.

Comment: This is the exact expected result you show in your question. If it is not what you want please edit your question and modify your expected output.

Comment: You are right.  I have included column numbers to see what is expected.  Had made a mistake in the last part.